# composing local nix packages

Tags: nix, nixos

I want to run a nix-shell with the following packages installed:

- aspell
- aspellDicts.en
- hello

I can't simply do: `nix-shell -p aspell aspellDicts.en hello --pure` as this will not correctly install the aspell dictionaries. Nix provides a `aspellWithDict` function that can be used to build aspell with dictionaries:

```
nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; aspellWithDicts (d: [d.en])'
```

I want to use the result of this build as a dependency in another local package (foo). This is how I'm currently achieving this:

./pkgs/aspell-with-dicts/default.nix:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

aspellWithDicts (d: [d.en])
```

./pkgs/foo/default.nix:

```
{stdenv, aspellWithDicts, hello}:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "foo";
    buildInputs = [ aspellWithDicts hello ];
}
```

./custom-packages.nix:

```
{ system ? builtins.currentSystem }:

let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> { inherit system; };

in

rec {
  aspellWithDicts = import ./pkgs/aspell-with-dicts;

  foo = import ./pkgs/foo {
    aspellWithDicts = aspellWithDicts;
    hello = pkgs.hello;
    stdenv = pkgs.stdenv;
  };
}
```

Running the shell works as expected: `nix-shell ./custom-packages.nix -A foo --pure`

So my solution works, but could this outcome be achieved in a more succinct idiomatic way?

Comment: Where do you want your `foo` package to go? Is it something you want to upstream into the NixPkgs repository? Or is it a package that you only ever want to install locally? Maybe you want to use it in your company?

Comment: For this instance `foo` is something that I just want to use locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this code more idiomatic, I have the following suggestions:

### `callPackage`

Use the `pkgs.callPackage` function. It will take care of passing the arguments that your derivation needs. This is why many files in NixPkgs look like `{ dependency, ...}: something`. The first argument is the function you want to inject dependencies into and the second argument is an attribute set that you can use to pass some dependencies manually.

By using `callPackage` you do not need to `import <nixpkgs> {}`, so your code will be easier to use in new contexts `<nixpkgs>` can't be used and it will evaluate a bit faster because it has to evaluate the NixPkgs fix-point only once.

(Of course you have to `import <nixpkgs>` once to get started, but after that, there should be no need.)

### `with`

In `pkgs/aspell-with-dicts/default.nix` you use a `with` keyword, which is ok, but in this case it does not really add value. I prefer to refer to variables explicitly, so prefer to read `pkgs.something` when it's used once or twice, or `inherit (pkgs) something` if it's use more often. This way the reader can easily determine where a variable comes from.

I do use it when experimenting with unfamiliar packages or functions, because maintenance is not an issue then.

### `pkgs/aspell-with-dicts/default.nix`

Unless you expect that your instantiation of aspell is something you want to reuse, it's probably easier to just construct it where you use it.

If you do expect to reuse a specific configuration of a package, you might want to make it a first class package by constructing it in an overlay.

---

That's it. I think the most important point is avoiding `<nixpkgs>` and apart from that it's already pretty idiomatic.

I don't know what your mysterious `foo` is, but if it's open source, please consider upstreaming it into NixPkgs. Nix has a very welcoming community in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Robert, which are all very helpful to my learning.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to build `foo`? What in `foo` you will use?

Assume you only want to use the shell via `nix-shell` and not want to build/install anything using `nix-build` or  `nix-env -i`, this should works.

The following `shell.nix`

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
with pkgs;

let
  myAspell = aspellWithDicts (d: [d.en]);
in
  stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "myShell";

    buildInputs = [myAspell hello];

    shellHooks = ''
      echo Im in $name.
      echo aspell is locate at ${myAspell}
      echo hello is locate at ${hello}
    '';
  }
```

will give you a shell with `aspell` and `hello`

```
$ nix-shell
Im in myShell.
aspell is locate at /nix/store/zcclppbibcg4nfkis6zqml8cnrlnx00b-aspell-env
hello is locate at /nix/store/gas2p68jqbzgb7zr96y5nc8j7nk61kkk-hello-2.10
```

---

If it is the case that `foo` have some code to build and install.

`mkDerivation` in `foo/default.nix` must have `src` field which could be `src = ./.;` or something like `fetchurl` or `fetchFromGithub` (see [document](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-using-stdenv) for examples).

Then you can use `callPackages` or `import` (depends on how the nix expression was written) with `foo/default.nix` as argument to bring what `foo` provided to use in this shell.

If you try to build this `shell.nix` (or `foo/default.nix`) it will failed with missing `src`

```
$ nix-build shell.nix 
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/20h8cva19irq8vn39i72j8iz40ivijhr-myShell.drv
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/r1f6qpxz91h5jkj7hzrmaymmzi9h1yml-myShell’
unpacking sources
variable $src or $srcs should point to the source
builder for ‘/nix/store/20h8cva19irq8vn39i72j8iz40ivijhr-myShell.drv’ failed with exit code 1
error: build of ‘/nix/store/20h8cva19irq8vn39i72j8iz40ivijhr-myShell.drv’ failed
```

Comment: Thanks wizzup, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the `buildInputs` in your example should actually be `[myAspell hello]`. If I make this amendment then your example works as expected.

Comment: If `shell.nix` did have a requirement to do some building, could it not simply be invoked using `nix-build`? Your `shell.nix` doesn't define a top level function and thus doesn't require dependencies to be passed in as arguments. So I'm unclear as to why there would be a need to use `callPackage` or `import` if `shell.nix` did build something? Appreciate your advise.

Comment: I mean `foo` doesn't seem to provide any output because `src` is missing so I just skip it. Running `nix-build foo/default.nix` would failed anyway.

Comment: thanks for the info, especially useful to see the use of 'shellHooks'.